# What's the difference between different ways to start a thread?

Tags: java, multithreading

I have a class named `MyThread` which extends the Thread class and implement the `run()` function.When I want to run it , I got two ways:

1. new a instance and call the function,like: `new MyThread().start()`
2. new a instance and transmit the instance to the construction function of Thread as a parameter and then call the start function of Thread. Like this: `(new Thread(new MyThread)).start();`

Anybody can just tell the difference?

Comment: Java `Thread` `implements` `Runnable`, therefore you can pass it as a reference to `Thread`, which takes a `Runnable` as a parameter.  Basically, the `Thread`, when executed will simply execute the `run` method of the `Runnable` it's pass.  If none is passed, it will simply execute it's own `run` method...

Comment: possible duplicate of ["implements Runnable" vs. "extends Thread"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/541487/implements-runnable-vs-extends-thread)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, you have two method to implement a multi-thread.

1. extend `Thread` and use `new MyThreand().start()` to start your thread.
2. implement `Runnable` interface. In this condition, you can use `(new Thread(new MyThread)).start()`;  to start a thread.

For detailed infomation, just refer to [oracle official doc.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html)

Comment: You Maybe shouldn't call the Runnable "MyThread" in the second option, that's very confusing.

Answer (score 19):

Because you've said your class *extends* `Thread`, the second one is a bit redundant. In your second example, you're not using your class as a [`Thread`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html), you're just using it as a [`Runnable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runnable.html).

Normally, you'd either extend `Thread` and then call its own `start` (your #1), **or** you'd implement `Runnable` and then use a `Thread` to run it (your #2). But you wouldn't extend `Thread` and then use another `Thread` to run it.

In terms of what's different, if you need to do anything to control or interrogate the thread, in your first case you'd use the `Thread` methods on the instance of *your* class; in the second case, you'd use them on the instance you create with `new Thread`. If you extend `Thread` but run it via #2, the `Thread` methods on your instance are irrelevant and could be confusing.

That last bit is probably clearer with examples:

Example of extending `Thread`:

```
class Foo extends Thread {
    public void run() {
        // ...
    }
}

// Create it
Foo foo = new Foo();

// Start it
foo.start();

// Wait for it to finish (for example)
foo.join();
```

Note we started and joined the thread via the `foo` reference.

Example of implementing `Runnable`:

```
class Foo implements Runnable {
    public void run() {
        // ...
    }
}

// Create it
Foo foo = new Foo();

// Create a Thread to run it
Thread thread = new Thread(foo);

// Start it
thread.start();

// Wait for it to finish (for example)
thread.join();
```

Note we started and joined the thread via the `thread` reference.

*Don't* do this:

```
class Foo extends Thread {
    public void run() {
        // ...
    }
}

// Create it
Foo foo = new Foo();

// Create a Thread to run it -- DON'T do this
Thread thread = new Thread(foo);

// Start it
thread.start();
```

...because now you have `Thread#join` available on both `foo` and `thread`; which is the right one to use? (The answer is: The one on `thread`, but it's confusing, so it's best not to do that.)

Comment: What are your reasons for preferring implementing `Runnable` rather than `Thread`?

Comment: @l0b0: I really should have phrased that differently (or, on reflection, just left it out), because it really depends on what the class is doing whether I prefer implementing or extending.

Comment: A `Thread` has it's responsibility. Adding another one to it is violation of single responsibility principle.

Comment: @JanHudec: That's why I said it would really depend on what I was doing with the class. :-)

Comment: I can't think of a single time when I thought about extending thread in a real life situation. I think the best idea is to just tell people not to do it and rely on the fact that anyone who should extend it will be knowledgeable enough to know when to break the rule.

Comment: This is the only answer that actually answers the question. What is the difference between the two.

Comment: Now we know the difference, but which method is the preferred one? Or are both equal?

Answer (score 1):

*The `MyThread` instance you are passing is just acting as `Runnable` and not as a separate Thread.*

There is basically *no difference* logically in both ways:

What `Thread` internally does on `start()` is, calls the `run()` method of `Runnable`.

And when you are doing `new Thread(new MyThread()).start()`, you are just being redundant as `Thread` itself implements `Runnable`.

But it will make no difference logically as the `run()` method of `MyThread` will be called by the new Thread.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't do this. Creating a thread does change some variables like the "number of unstarted threads" in `ThreadGroup`.

While it shouldn't exactly cause problems, it's bad style and will confuse people ("Why did he do that? There *must* be a good reason!").

Answer (score 1):

If your class itself extends `Thread` you can follow your first way:

```
MyThread myThread = new MyThread();
myThread.start();
```

If you look into the [JavaDoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html), you'll see that your second way is targeted towards classes that (just) implement `Runnable` (which means that your class just needs to implement `run()` method).

```
public class MyClass implements Runnable {
     public void run() { ... }
}

Thread thread = new Thread(new MyClass());
thread.start();
```

The difference is that `Runnable` is only an interface whereas `Thread` is a class. This means that if you want to have your logic as part of a class which needs for some reason to extend a different class, then you can still implement `Runnable` and use the second way.

Answer (score 1):

**Thread** itself is an implementation of `Runnable`. When create an instance of `Thread` and start it, it will executes it's own `run()` method. If *non-null* `Runnable target` is given to it's constructor, then it will invoke it's target's `run()` method as is evident from the implemented `run()` method of `Thread` class:

```
@Override
    public void run() {
        if (target != null) {
            target.run();
        }
    }
```

The two ways to create a new thread of execution:

1. First one is to declare a class(i.e. `PThread`) to be a subclass of `Thread`: `PThread extends PThread` and should override the `run` method of `class` Thread. We can then easily create instantiate of this class and invoke `start()` on it:

   ```
   PThread pThread = new PThread(args);
   pThread.start();
   ```
2. Second one is to declare a class that implements the `Runnable` interface: `RThread implements Runnable` then implements the `run` method. We will have to instantiate the `RThread` and pass it to a `Thread` instance as a `Runnable` target:

   ```
    RunThread rThread = new RunThread(args); // args constructor argument if required 
    Thread t = new Thread(rThread);
    t.start();
   ```

As you have seen from the above way to start a thread, It is actually allowed a class extending a `Thread`, such as `PThread` to be passed to a new `Thread` constructor as a `Runnable` target to start it. Because `Thread` itself is an implementation of `Runnable`.

```
   PThread pThread = new PThread(args);
   Thread t = new Thread(pThread);  
         // allowed as pThread is extending Thread and hence, 
         //an implementation of Runnable 
   t.start();
```

But this operation is unnecessary or, rather you should not do it. As `pThread` is already a `Thread`, we could just call `pThread.start()` to executes it's `run()` method, which is the heart of a `Thread`. Creating another thread just to execute `pThread` is just extra overhead as it will not do anything other than executing `pThread`'s `run()` method.

However, you should not actually use an extension of `Thread` at all. Because,

**implementing Runnable is always preferable over extending a Thread:**

- Inheriting all *Thread methods* are additional overhead just for representing a Task which can can be done easily with `Runnable`.
- Implementing `Runnable` to a Class still allows us to extend it to other class if necessary.
- In OOP, extending a class generally means adding new functionality, modifying or improving behaviors. If we are not making any modification on `Thread` or changing it's behavior,  than use `Runnable interface` instead.
- `Runnable` interface represent a Task which can be executed by either plain `Thread` or `Executors` or any other means. so logical separation of Task as `Runnable` than `Thread` is good design decision.
- [**`Executors`**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html), which makes life easier with multi-threading  accepts `Runnable` as task.

**Reference:**

1. [Class Thread](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html)
2. [Difference between Thread class and Runnable interface](http://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2012/01/difference-thread-vs-runnable-interface.html)

Answer (score 0):

(new Thread(new MyThread)).start();

each Thread implements Runnable; in this case MyThread instance is used as Runnable the new thread calls the run method implemented by MyThread. You will not be able to stop the thread ( or control it by any means) by using MyThread.

Answer (score 0):

There are absolutely no difference between  how you start the Thread `(class implementing Runnable or extending Thread class)`

It's only the abstraction that you apply, note `(Runnable object, is more general, because the Runnable object can subclass a class other than Thread)` **Good Coding Practice.**

```
In both of the cases Thread.start() will called
```